# How to set the browser name parameter in the protractor script

Tags: protractor

I have started using protractor and now able to execute same test script on multiple browsers by doing below changes in protractor.conf.js file.

```
multiCapabilities: [{
'browserName': 'chrome'
}, {
'browserName': 'firefox'
}],
```

Now, I would like to parameterized my tests to provide browser name on which it should run. For e.g.: I have 2 test cases, 1 should run on chrome and other should run on firefox. This should be handled by providing browser name parameter in the test itself. Below is my first test case. Can you please help me to pass the browser name parameter in it.

```
'use strict';

/* https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/toc.md */

describe('Login and Logout Test Case', function () {

    //before Each unittests case load the login page
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get('#/login');
    });

    it('unittests the scenario when the user clicks on Dutch', function () {

        //The link for Dutch language from the login page is clicked

        element(by.id('username')).sendKeys('kaustubhsaxena');
        element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('saxena');

        element(by.id('login')).click();

        browser.quit();

     });
});
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What behaviour would you like to test that is different for each browser?

Comment: we wanted to check the compatibility of application with different browsers. That's the reason we would like to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything specific that should behave differently for different browsers, or should each browser behave identically from the users' point of view?

Comment: It should behave same.

Comment: then why is `multiCapabilities` not suitable?

Comment: ... And why not run all tests on all browsers?

Comment: to save time. Going ahead we have might have 100 test cases, and we wanted to run 50 on chrome and remaining on firefox. Then it will reduce time and check the compatibility as well. Anyhow, do you have any suggestion to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To get the browser name, you can use [`browser.getCapabilities()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCapabilities):

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function(capabilities) {
    // Outputs 'chrome' when on Chrome
    console.log(capabilities.caps_.browserName);
});
```

If waiting until a promise is resolved isn't good for your use case, then a hackier way that works on my system is to access the resolved/fulfilled session object directly:

```
// Outputs 'chrome' when on Chrome
console.log(browser.driver.session_.value_.caps_.caps_.browserName);
```